# How can I switch the y-axis in the Konva.js stage to start from bottom to top instead of top to bottom?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva

I would like to plot data from a Cartesian coordinate system. With the origin (0/0) starting on the bottom left. Within HTML-canvas the origin is in the top-left. How do I switch the y-axis (in react-konva or konva)?

```
function App() {
  const points = [0, 0, 400, 400];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
        <Layer>
          <Line points={points} stroke="red" strokeWidth={10} />
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As an example the provided code draws a line from to top left towards the center. I would like to start it from the bottom left by switching the y-axis.

All the best, Stefan

Answer (score 1):

### Way 1: Use negative scaleY

The first way is to just flip y-axis with `scaleY={-1}`. Also, you will need to change `y` of the stage, so the content is visible.

```js
function App() {
  const points = [0, 0, 400, 400];

  return (
    <Stage
      width={window.innerWidth}
      height={window.innerHeight}
      scaleY={-1}
      y={window.innerHeight}
    >
      <Layer>
        <Line points={points} stroke="red" strokeWidth={10} />
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
}
```

But you should be careful with this approach, meaning that all drawings are flipped. So if you have a text on the stage it will be inverted too.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-revert-y-axis-ldqgd

### Way 2: calculate positions manually:

```js
function invertPoints(points, height = window.innerHeight) {
   return points.map((value, index) => {
      // ignore `x` coordinate change
      if (index % 2 === 0) {
         return value;
      }
      //
      return height - value;
   });
}

function App() {
  const points = invertPoints([0, 0, 400, 400], window.innerHeight);

  return (
    <Stage
      width={window.innerWidth}
      height={window.innerHeight}
    >
      <Layer>
        <Line points={points} stroke="red" strokeWidth={10} />
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-revert-y-axis-manually-0lwiv?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Have you ever considered adding a feature to flip the axis of a layer? That way the shapes / plot points could be drawn inversely on a flipped layer and the text could be output on a non-flipped layer. If you were considering it then for text positioning it would be great to have a conversion between any point on either layer.  This is not a must-have or even highly desirable because there are many charting libs out there !

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!
I think I will go for option 1 but 2 is interesting too. Good to have both options.